# How to find $\int_0^1\!\! \left(\frac1{\log^2\left(1-x\right)}-\frac1{x^2}+\frac1x-\frac1{12}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

How to show that

$$\int_0^1\!\! \left(\frac1{\log^2\left(1-x\right)}-\frac1{x^2}+\frac1x-\frac1{12}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}x=\frac{\ln{(2\pi)}}{12}-\frac{5}{24}+\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}$$ ?

I have no any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just $\dfrac{1}{\log^2 (1-x)}$? It won't make sense when $x > 1$.

Comment: i guess your integration interval is somehow incorrect

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n}{n^2}=-\zeta'(2).$

Comment: This paper might be quiet helpful:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3902.pdf

Comment: Similarly to what I wrote in my very first comment to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607314), your integral is nothing more than a rigorous way of asking for a regularization of $$\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln^k(1-x)~x^{n-1}~dx~=~\frac{d^k}{dm^k}~\int_0^1(1-x)^{m-1}~x^{n-1}~dx~=~\frac{d^k}{dm^k}~B(m,n)$$ to negative values of *n*, where *B* represents Euler's famous [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Also, since *k* is negative as well, we are dealing with [integration rather than differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral).