# Improper Integral $\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^3}-\frac1{x^2\cosh^2(x)}\right)dx = \frac{7\zeta(3)}{\pi^2} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}$
$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}{\left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^3} - \frac{\sech^2(x)}{x^2} \right)\ dx }= \frac{7\zeta(3)}{\pi^2} $

**What I tried**

I simplified it to -

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh(2x) - 2x}{x^3 \cosh^2(x)} \ dx}$

Then I don't know how to solve. I tried Feynman's method

$\displaystyle I(a) = \int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh(ax) - ax}{x^3 \cosh^2(x)} \ dx}$

But then too it didn't help much.

I thought of replacing them with trigonometric forms and then complex number real and imaginary part but wasn't helpful much.

Please try to avoid complex analysis.

Comment: residue theorem finish this integral quickly

Comment: Since the function is even we can extend the range of integration to $(-  \infty,\infty)$. It is also not too difficult to see that the integrand $f(z)$ as a function of a complex variable $z$ is $\sim \mathcal{O}(|z|^{-2})$ as $|z|\rightarrow \infty$ and also bounded at the origin. We can therefore choose a big semicircle in the u.h.p. as an contour of integration. We obtain

$$
2I=2 \pi i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{res}\left(f(z),z=\frac{i n \pi}{2}\right)
$$ 

....

Comment: ...with $\text{res}\left(f(z),z=\frac{i n \pi}{2}\right)=\frac{-8 i }{\pi^3 (2n-1)^3}$ we get

>$$
I=\frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1} {(2n-1)^3}=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}
$$

Comment: by the way your second integral is wrong...how can we get an odd function out of an even one=?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tanh(x)%2Fx%5E3-1%2F(x%5E2+Cosh(x)%5E2)-(sinh(2x)-2x)%2F(x%5E2+cosh(x)%5E2)

Comment: Thanks to @tired, I saw OP's typo. When simplifying the integral, the denominator should become $x^3 \cosh^2 x$. That case, my answer below makes no sense. I am deleting it.

Comment: forget it, it is boring. you can use the same method as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607314/conjecture-large-int-0-infty-left-frac1x4-frac12x3-frac112-x2/1607377#1607377 but @tired 's method with the residue theorem is much better.

Comment: @tired: I didn't see your comment until after I posted my answer.  If you want to add your comment as an answer, I can delete mine.

Comment: @robjohn i'm glad that someone put this idea into an answer (+1)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{\tanh\pars{x} \over x^{3}} - {1 \over x^{2}\cosh^{2}\pars{x}}}\,\dd x = {7 \over \pi^{2}}\,\zeta\pars{3}}
\approx 0.8526\ \Large ?}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{\tanh\pars{x} \over x^{3}} - {1 \over x^{2}\cosh^{2}\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tanh\pars{x} - x \over x^{3}}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tanh^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &
-\,\half\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{\tanh\pars{x} - x}
\,\dd\pars{1 \over x^{2}} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tanh^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mrm{sech}^{2}\pars{x}  - 1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tanh^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x =
\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tanh^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
32\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\,\,\ \underbrace{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \bracks{\pars{2k + 1}\pi}^{\, 2} + 4x^{2}}\,
{1 \over \bracks{\pars{2n + 1}\pi}^{\, 2} + 4x^{2}}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{1 \over 8\pi^{2}\pars{2k + 1}\pars{2n + 1}\pars{k + n + 1}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{4 \over \pi^{2}}\
\underbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{H_{k} + 2\ln\pars{2} \over \pars{2k + 1}^{2}}}
_{\ds{{7 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}}}\label{2}\tag{2} =
\color{#f00}{{7 \over \pi^{2}}\,\zeta\pars{3}}
\end{align}
Note that

- In \eqref{1}, we use the identity
  $\ds{{\tanh\pars{x} \over x} =
  8\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \bracks{\pars{2j + 1}\pi}^{\, 2} + 4x^{2}}}$
- The sum over $\ds{n}$, in \eqref{1}, yields a Digamma Function term
  $\ds{\Psi\pars{1 + k}}$ which explains the appearance of the *Harmonic Number* $\ds{H_{k} = \Psi\pars{1 + k} + \gamma}$. $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
  *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*.
- $\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{H_{k} \over \pars{2k + 1}^{2}} =
  {1 \over 4}\bracks{7\zeta\pars{3} - \pi^{2}\ln\pars{2}}}$ is a *well known* result.
- $\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2k + 1}^{2}} =
  {1 \over 8}\,\pi^{2}}$.

Comment: Check other evaluations of $\int_0^\infty \tanh^2 x / x^2 \, dx $ [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582943/integral-int-0-infty-frac-tanh2xx2dx)

Comment: @nospoon Thanks for your information. I was not aware of that page. I was familiar with $\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\tanh(x) \over x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ which appears in Superconductivity Theory, Charge and Spin Density Waves, etc... The usual approach is integration by parts which was my first attempt. That was a messy. Then, I could remember the $\tanh(x)/x$ expansion which is widely known in Superconductivity. In Superconductivity, the above mentioned integral is evaluated for large but finite $\Lambda$. The page you showed me has a lot of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

**A Residue Calculus Approach**

At $z=\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi i$, the residue of $\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^3}$ is $\frac{i}{\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\right)^3}$ and the residue of $\frac1{x^2\cosh^2(x)}$ is $\frac {2i}{\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\right)^3}$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^3}-\frac1{x^2\cosh^2(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^3}-\frac1{x^2\cosh^2(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i}\left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^3}-\frac1{x^2\cosh^2(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\[6pt]
&=\pi i\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[\frac{i}{\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\right)^3}-\frac{2i}{\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\right)^3}\right]\tag{4}\\
&=\frac8{\pi^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^3}\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: the integrand is even
$(3)$: the integrand vanishes at $x=\pm\infty$ and has no sinularities in $-1\lt\mathrm{Im}(z)\lt0$
$(4)$: the integrand vanishes like $\frac1{z^2}$ on $\mathrm{Im}(z)\in\mathbb{Z}\pi$
$\phantom{\text{(4): }}$and like $\frac1{z^3}$ as $|\mathrm{Re}(z)|\to\infty$
$\phantom{\text{(4): }}$so the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues
$(5)$: algebra
$(6)$: note that the sum is $\frac78\zeta(3)$

Comment: hey @robjohn may i ask why you shift the path of integration to $-i$? I don't see the reason at the moment...

Comment: @tired: it avoids the singularity at $0$. The difference does not have a singularity at $0$, but we are computing the residues after we have separated the functions. The functions are even, so they have $0$ residue at $0$, but they are like $\frac1{z^2}$ near $0$, so we can't just take a small semi-circle around $0$ and discount it. This just avoids having to worry about $0$ at all.

Answer (score 9):

Integrating by parts we get $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\tanh\left(x\right)}{x^{3}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)dx= $$ $$-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\left(-\frac{\tanh\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)}+2\frac{\tanh\left(x\right)}{\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)dx$$ so $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\tanh\left(x\right)}{x^{3}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)dx=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh\left(x\right)}{x\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)}dx
 $$ and now taking $x=-\log\left(u\right)
 $ we get $$I=4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(u^{2}-1\right)u}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{3}\log\left(u\right)}du=4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{3}-u}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{3}\log\left(u\right)}du
 $$ $$=4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{3}}\int_{1}^{3}u^{z}dzdu=4\int_{1}^{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{z}}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{3}}dudz
 $$ and the last integral can be written in terms of the [Gauss hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{z}}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{3}}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{z/2-1/2}}{\left(u+1\right)^{3}}du=\frac{1}{z+1}\,_{2}F_{1}\left(3,\frac{z+1}{2},1+\frac{z+1}{2},-1\right)
 $$ and this particular hypergeometric function has a “closed form” in terms of Digamma function, so we have $$ I=\frac{1}{8}\int_{1}^{3}\left(z^{2}-4z+3\right)\left(\psi\left(\frac{z+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)\right)dz-\frac{1}{8}\int_{1}^{3}2z-8dz.
 $$ Now note that every single term is in the form $$a\int_{1}^{3}z^{b}\psi\left(\frac{z+c}{4}\right)dz=4a\int_{(1+c)/4}^{(3+c)/4}\left(4v-c\right)^{b}\psi\left(v\right)dv
 $$ with $b=0,1,2
 $ and $c=1,3
 $ so let us consider the case $b=0$. We have $$\int_{(1+c)/4}^{(3+c)/4}\psi\left(v\right)dv=\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3+c}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+c}{4}\right)}\right)
 $$ if $b=1
 $ we have, integrating by parts, $$\int_{(1+c)/4}^{(3+c)/4}v\psi\left(v\right)dv=\left(v\log\left(\Gamma\left(v\right)\right)-\psi^{\left(-2\right)}\left(v\right)\right)_{(1+c)/4}^{(3+c)/4}$$ and if $b=2$ we have $$\int_{(1+c)/4}^{(3+c)/4}v^{2}\psi\left(v\right)dv=\left(v^{2}\log\left(\Gamma\left(v\right)\right)-2v\psi^{\left(-2\right)}\left(v\right)+3\psi^{\left(-3\right)}\left(v\right)\right)_{(1+c)/4}^{(3+c)/4}$$ so combining this result and the closed form about [polygamma at negative orders](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/polyg.htm) we obtain $$I=\color{red}{\frac{7\zeta\left(3\right)}{\pi^{2}}}$$ as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm very late in this thread, but please allow me to share my method. It's a bit more easier to come up with, if I do say so myself...

First, I manipulate the integral to a more friendly form. Namely,
$\require{AMScd}$

\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^{\infty}{\left[ \frac{\tanh \left( x \right)}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2\cosh ^2\left( x \right)} \right] \mathrm{d}x}
\\&
=\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\tanh \left( x \right) -x}{x^3}\mathrm{d}x}+\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh ^2\left( x \right)}{x^2\cosh ^2\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}
\\&
\stackrel{\mathrm{I.B.P}}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}\left. \frac{x-\tanh \left( x \right)}{2x^2} \right|_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh ^2\left( x \right)}{x^2\cosh ^2\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}+\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh ^2\left( x \right)}{x^2\cosh ^2\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}
\\&
=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh ^2\left( x \right)}{x^2\cosh ^2\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}\stackrel{\mathrm{I.B.P}}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}\left. -\frac{\sinh ^2\left( x \right)}{2x\cosh ^2\left( x \right)} \right|_{0}^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh \left( x \right)}{x\cosh ^3\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}
\\&
=\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh \left( x \right)}{x\cosh ^3\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}
\end{align*}

Then, I define $I(t)$, and use leibniz rule on it.
\begin{align*}
I\left( t \right) &\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sinh \left( tx \right)}{x\cosh ^3\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}
\\
I'\left( t \right) &=\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\cosh \left( tx \right)}{\cosh ^3\left( x \right)}\mathrm{d}x}
\stackrel{e^{-x}=s}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}4\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{s^t+s^{-t}}{s\left( s+s^{-1} \right) ^3}\mathrm{d}x}
\\&
\stackrel{s\rightsquigarrow \frac{1}{s}}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}4\int_0^1{\frac{s^t+s^{-t}}{s\left( s+s^{-1} \right) ^3}\mathrm{d}x}
=2\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{s^{2+t}+s^{2-t}}{\left( s^2+1 \right) ^3}\mathrm{d}x}
\\&
\stackrel{s^2=u}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{u^{\frac{3+t}{2}-1}+u^{\frac{3-t}{2}-1}}{\left( u+1 \right) ^{\frac{3+t}{2}+\frac{3-t}{2}}}\mathrm{d}x}=2\mathrm{B}\left( \frac{3+t}{2}, \frac{3-t}{2} \right) 
\\&
=\Gamma \left( \frac{3+t}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{3-t}{2} \right) 
=\frac{\pi \left( 1-t^2 \right)}{4\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2}t \right)}
\end{align*}

Then I integrated that from 0 to 1.
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^1{I'\left( t \right) \mathrm{d}t}=\int_0^1{\frac{\pi \left( 1-t^2 \right)}{4\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}t \right)}\mathrm{d}t}
\\&
\stackrel{\frac{t\pi}{2}\rightsquigarrow t}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}\frac{1}{2\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi ^2-4t^2}{\cos \left( t \right)}\mathrm{d}t}\stackrel{\frac{\pi}{2}-t\rightsquigarrow t}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}\frac{2}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{t\left( \pi -t \right)}{\sin \left( t \right)}\mathrm{d}t}
\\&
\stackrel{\mathrm{I.B.P}}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}\left. \frac{2}{\pi ^2}t\left( \pi -t \right) \ln \left( \tan \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) \right) \right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{2}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left( 2t-\pi \right) \ln \left( \tan \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\&
\stackrel{\frac{t}{2}\rightsquigarrow t}{\begin{CD}@=\end{CD}}\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\left( 4t-\pi \right) \ln \left( \tan \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\&
=\underset{t\rightsquigarrow t}{\underbrace{\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\left( 4t-\pi \right) \ln \left( \sin \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}}}-\underset{t\rightsquigarrow \frac{\pi}{2}-t}{\underbrace{\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\left( 4t-\pi \right) \ln \left( \cos \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}}}
\\&
=\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\left( 4t-\pi \right) \ln \left( \sin \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}+\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left( 4t-\pi \right) \ln \left( \sin \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\&
=\frac{16}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{t\ln \left( \sin \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}-\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\ln \left( \sin \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\end{align*}

the right one evaluates to $-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( 2 \right) $. Plus, using the fourier expansion of $\ln \left( \sin \left( t \right) \right) $

\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{16}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{t\ln \left( \sin \left( t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\\&
=-\frac{16}{\pi ^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left( t\ln \left( 2 \right) +t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos \left( 2nt \right)}{n}} \right) \mathrm{d}t}+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\\&
=-\frac{16}{\pi ^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{t\cos \left( 2nt \right) \mathrm{d}t}=\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1-\cos \left( \pi n \right)}{n^3}}
\\&
=\frac{8}{\pi ^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\left( 2n-1 \right) ^3}}=\frac{8}{\pi ^2}\frac{7}{8}\zeta \left( 3 \right) =\frac{7}{\pi ^2}\zeta \left( 3 \right) 
\end{align*}