# Gamma Infinite Summation $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+s)}{n!}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

Avoiding the analytic continuation of extended binomial theorem, 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{n!}\,x^n = \frac{\Gamma(z)}{(1-x)^z} \quad\colon\space |x|\lt1 $$

> How to prove: 
>   $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+s)}{n!} = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\, \frac{s}{1!}+\frac{s(s+1)}{2!}+\cdots = -1 \quad\colon\space Re\{s\}\lt0 $$

Comment: @mick, Calculate [the limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BGamma%5Bx-5%5D%2F0!%2BGamma%5Bx-4%5D%2F1!%2BGamma%5Bx-3%5D%2F2!%2BGamma%5Bx-2%5D%2F3!%2BGamma%5Bx-1%5D%2F4!%2BGamma%5Bx%5D%2F5!,x-%3E0%5D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We find that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\Gamma(k+s)}{k!} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1+s)}{n!s} \tag{*}$$

for all $n = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$. Indeed, this is easily proved by the mathematical induction:

1. When $n = 0$, it boils down to the equality $\Gamma(s) = \frac{\Gamma(1+s)}{s}$, which is of course true.
2. Assuming that $\text{(*)}$ is true for $n \geq 0$, then

   \begin{align*}
   \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{\Gamma(k+s)}{k!}
   &= \frac{\Gamma(n+1+s)}{n!s} + \frac{\Gamma(n+1+s)}{(n+1)!} \\
   &= \frac{(n+1+s)\Gamma(n+1+s)}{(n+1)!s}
    = \frac{\Gamma(n+2+s)}{(n+1)!s}
   \end{align*}

Therefore $\text{(*)}$ is true for all $n \geq 0$. Now the conclusion follows by taking $n\to\infty$. (Stirling's formula is enough for this purpose.)

---

*Remark.* The identity $\text{(*)}$ becomes more natural once we recognize it as a disguise of the famous formula

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{k+s-1}{k} = \binom{n+s}{n}. $$

When $s$ is a positive integer, this indeed follows from the hockey-stick argument.

Comment: Imho that is a bit too short

Comment: @mick, Is there anything you want me to improve?

Comment: More details about the induction etc

Comment: Beauty is Simplicity (+1). However, for the limit, $\{\,\lim\frac{\Gamma(N+s)}{s\,\Gamma(N)}=0\,\colon{\small Re\{s\}\lt0}\,\}$ , I would use [the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) $\{\,\lim\frac{\Gamma(N+s)}{N^s\,\Gamma(N)}=1\,\colon{\small s\in\mathbb{C}}\,\}$. Interestingly you mentioned other method, please expound. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\Re\pars{s} < 0}$:

\begin{align}
\left.\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{n + s} \over n!}
\,\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{s}\ <\ 0} & =
\pars{s - 1}!\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + s - 1 \choose n} =
\pars{s - 1}!\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-s \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{s - 1}!\,\bracks{1 + \pars{-1}}^{\,-s} = \bbx{\ds{0}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(z) = \int_0 ^{\infty} x^{z-1} e^{-x} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \Gamma(n+s)}{n!} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0 ^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+s-1} e^{-x}}{n!} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Now invert the sum & integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0 ^{\infty} x^{s-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^{n} }{n!}  e^{-x}dx =\int_0 ^{\infty} x^{s-1} dx = \left[ \frac{x^s}{s} \right]_0 ^{\infty}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now $x^s$ will tend to zero provided $ Re(s)< 0$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s) \\
\Gamma(s+2) = s(s+1) \Gamma(s) \\
\Gamma(s+n) = s(s+1) \cdots (s+n-1)  \Gamma(s)
\end{eqnarray*}
Divide the equation by $\Gamma(s)$ and move the first term to the right hand side.

Comment: The integral is only valid for $Re\{z\}>0$

Comment: I had a feeling that might be a validity range issue. I also would have need to justify inverting the sum & integral.